# Cannot install RMagic gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'd like to install RMagic gem, I got “Can't find Magick-config” so I installed

```
 $ sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

but now I get following output:

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby -r
>   ./siteconf20150526-12203-xr9xf7.rb extconf.rb  checking for Ruby
>   version >= 1.8.5... yes checking for gcc... yes checking for
>   Magick-config... yes checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... ***
>   extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason,
>   probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the
>   mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>           --with-opt-dir
>           --without-opt-dir
>           --with-opt-include
>           --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>           --with-opt-lib
>           --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>           --with-make-prog
>           --without-make-prog
>           --srcdir=.
>           --curdir
>           --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby extconf.rb:154:in ``': No such file or directory - convert
>   (Errno::ENOENT)
>           from extconf.rb:154:in `block in <main>'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:918:in`block
>   in checking_for'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block
>   (2 levels) in postpone'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in`open'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block
>   in postpone'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in`open'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:347:in
>   `postpone'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:917:in`
>   checking_for'
>           from extconf.rb:151:in `'
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rmagick-2.13.4 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/rmagick-2.13.4/gem_make.out

Could someone help me solve it?

Comment: what OS are you using? ubuntu?

Comment: I'm working on website c9.io

Comment: Does c9.io allow you to install third party libraries? I haven't used c9.io before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at where it fails (which was hard to work out because your newlines got swallowed somewhere):

```
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... * extconf.rb failed *
```

This check didn't get a "yes", which suggests that the `libmagickwand-dev` package you installed did not provide a version of ImageMagic >= 6.4.9 which is apparently the version that the rmagick gem version 2.13.4 requires.

Either get a newer ImageMagick or an older rmagick gem.

Comment: I installed older version rmagick and it works, thank you very much, I'm quite new in rails

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install ImageMagick. Usually, not having the right dependencies is the culprit.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php

Comment: His first line says that he installed it.

Comment: "libmagickwand-dev" is a version of ImageMagick? I didn't know that. You typically get the error, when you don't have ImageMagick properly installed.

Comment: It's all good, I appreciate it if you could un-"down-vote" my answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: I tried, Stack Overflow told me it was locked now :(

Answer (score 0):

After trying the above solutions and still not working .. i tried this one
         sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
did the trick for me